# NodeJs: Paystack verification response

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, verification

Tried working around the paystack verifiaction API, the documentation does not provide a clear part as to how to do this, the response i get using a chained promise (i.e. .then()) is a buffer and bunch of request parameters, and following it as the documentation descrives returns the following error.

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',   syscall: 'connect',
> address: '127.0.0.1',   port: 443 }

Any assistance as to how to go about this please.

Answer (score 1):

so, I was able to get the response as against what was stated in the documentation:
first, get the response from the paystack API
then return the response with the json method as thus

> .then(response=>response.json)
> .then(result=>console.log(result)); //this will return the appropriate data from the verification process.